# In Markov process, how to solve $P(X_n=1)$

Tags: markov-process, transition-matrix

Let $X_n$ is Markov chain for $n\geq 0$ and state space is $E=\{1,2,3\}$. One-step transition probability matrix is
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 p_{11}&  p_{12}&  p_{13}\\
 p_{21}&  p_{22}&  p_{23}\\
 p_{31}&  p_{32}&  p_{33}\\
\end{matrix} \right] 
$$
how can I solve $P(X_n =1)$?

As far as I know, if state space is $E=\{1,2\}$ and the one-step transition probability matrix's size is $2\times2$, $i.e.$
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 p_{11}&  p_{12}\\
 p_{21}&  p_{22}\\
\end{matrix} \right] 
$$
we have
$$
\begin{split}
q_n&=P\left( X_n=1 \right) 
\\
&=P\left( X_n=1\left| X_{n-1}=1 \right. \right) P\left( X_{n-1}=1 \right) +P\left( X_n=1\left| X_{n-1}=2 \right. \right) P\left( X_{n-1}=2 \right) 
\\
&=p_{11}P\left( X_{n-1}=1 \right) +p_{21}P\left( X_{n-1}=2 \right) 
\\
&=p_{11}q_n+p_{21}\left( 1-q_n \right) 
\\
&=\left( p_{11}-p_{21} \right) q_n+p_{21}
\end{split}
$$
then, we have
$$
q_n-\frac{p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{21}}=\left( p_{11}-p_{21} \right) \left( q_n-\frac{p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{21}} \right) 
$$
$i.e.$,$\{q_n-\frac{p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{21}}\}$ is geometric sequence. Therefore, if we know $P(X_0=1)=p_1$ and $P(X_0=2)=p_2$, we can easily find that
$$
\begin{split}
P\left( X_n=1 \right) &=q_n
\\
&=q_0\left( p_{11}-p_{21} \right) ^n+\frac{p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{21}}
\\
&=P\left( X_0=1 \right) \left( p_{11}-p_{21} \right) ^n+\frac{p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{21}}
\\
&=p_1\left( p_{11}-p_{21} \right) ^n+\frac{p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{21}}
\end{split}
$$
However, when the one-step transition probability matrix's size is to $3\times 3$, I can not find the recursion formula as above, and I even don't know how to solve this question.

Comment: You perform an eigenanalysis of $P$.  There is no general formula once the dimension of $P$ exceeds $2\times 2.$  (The answers are algebraic functions of roots of polynomials, implying there *are* (nasty) formulas for three- and four-state chains, but not for anything larger.) See [examples on our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=markov+eigenvector+transition+matrix) for details.  Sometimes, when the components of $P$ have nice relationships, formulas can be found: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87440/919 for one example with three states.