# Is X a negative binomial? ( Tosses of dice)

Tags: probability, self-study

Two dice are tossed independently until each pair has appeared at least once. Find the expected number of tosses needed and the standard deviation of this number of tosses.

**My attempt**

Let X be the random variable that counts the number of tosses needed until each pair appears at least once. Let $X_1$  be a random variable that counts the number of tosses until the first "new" pair appear, $X_2$ counts the number of adittional tosses, after the first "new" pair until the second "new" pair appears and so on until $X_{36}$. Then,

$$X=X_1+X_2+...+X_{36}$$

We can see that each $ X_i$ is a geometric random variable with $p=\frac{1}{36}$ (that count the number of trials).And since the tosses are independent, I thought that I could say that they are independent. But I am not sure about the last affirmation. If they are indeed independent, I could say that $X$ is negatove binomial, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Several interpretations of the problem seem possible, depending on what a "pair" is. You have taken it to be *any ordered pair* of outcomes of two distinguishable dice. It would also be interpreted to be *any unordered pair* or even any outcome in which both dice show the same result. In the first and third interpretations, this is just the **Coupon Collector Problem** with equal probabilities, which has been extensively discussed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48396. In the second interpretation it has unequal probabilities, but the solution methods are similar.

Comment: Searching here on *coupon collector problem* turns up a number of related posts, one or two of which have the odd interesting bit of additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_i$ is a geometric random variable with $p_i = \left(36 - (i - 1)\right)/36$.

$X_i$ is the number of tosses until the *next* new pair; *any new* pair counts. Until $X_i$ you have observed $i - 1$ distinct pairs, and you are waiting for  *any* of the $36 - (i - 1)$ remaining pairs to roll up.

For example, take $i = 1$, then $p_1 = 1$, because in the very first toss any pair is a new pair.

So, no! this is not negative binomial. Yes, the $X_i$ are independent random variables, but the $p_i$ are not the same.

Comment: Indeed, your are totally correct. But how to calculatethe standard deviation (or the variance) using this fact?

Comment: Never mind, they are independent!

Comment: @Giiovanna you have a summation of _independent_ variables, and the expected value of the sum is sum of expected values, and using the independence, similarly for variance.