# How do I find the expected coverage of the domain after K ranges are selected?

Tags: expected-value, range

If I have a domain of 0 to 1000000 (but I doubt the domain matters, just that the ranges can overlap). I then chose 1% ranges uniformly, allowing for ranges to overlap completely or partially.

How do I find the expected percent of the domain that will be covered after K selections?

This seems like a simple selection with replacement but since the ranges can overlap I'm not sure how to find it. Is it as simple as repeatedly adding the useful part of the next selection? The first selection covers 1% if the domain. The second selection also covers 1% of the domain but since only 99% is uncovered, the expected coverage of the second selection is 0.99%, thus after 2 selections it is 1.99%...and so on with decreasing returns on each selection?

An example might be:

Domain: 0-999999 (in a dense sequence)
Percent selected per instance: 1%
Selection count: 50
Each range is chosen uniformly.
And I want to know what the expected % of the whole domain was covered (or remains uncovered as it provides the same information).

So on the first choice maybe the range is 128774-138773. Now after one selection 1% of the values have been covered. The second selection is 250791-260790 and now 2% is selected (but it also could have been 131456-141455 which would have overlapped with the first range resulting in less than 2% currently being covered). And so on for the remaining 48 selections.

Comment: Can you add some more context here? This is awfully abstract at present.

Comment: how are you choosing the locations of (say) the left edge of the subranges?

Comment: Each selected range can start anywhere from 0 to MAX - range width, so in the example I choose an integer between 0 and 999000 uniformly.

Comment: The endpoints must fall on integers?

Comment: Yes, endpoints must be integers. But if a solution assumed continuous it would be correct up to some % for discrete ranges like these right?

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate this by simplifying the problem: say you have $N$ bins, and you place $M$ marbles into them selecting a bin at random; you want to count the number of bins with at least one marble.  You relate this estimate to your real problem by dividing the size of the domain by the "percent selected per instance".

The formula for the simplified model is going to look a lot like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48396/how-often-do-you-have-to-roll-a-6-sided-dice-to-obtain-every-number-at-least-onc).

Comment: please reproduce the formula in case the link changes in the future