# partial set coverage sampling rule

Tags: sampling, bootstrap, resampling

Is there a general relationship that gives the total number of drawn samples (d) on average required to have at least percent (p) of distinct samples in a set size N when sampling randomly with replacement?

If I have 200 distinct elements (N) in the bag, and I sample with replacement, I can estimate that around 10^2.5 drawn samples (d) yields about 80% (p) of those elements.  If I have 2000 samples then about 10^3.5 yields 80%.

Here is code that allows the eyeball estimate of 10^3.5 from 2000 and 80%:

```
#total samples
N <- 2000

#how many to draw
samp_list <- 10^seq(from=2, to=4.0, length.out=1000) %>% round()

res <- 0*samp_list

for(i in 1:length(samp_list)){
  
  #draw
  y <- sample(1:N, samp_list[i], replace=T)
  
  #what percent of unique is drawn
  res[i] <- (length(unique(y))/N)
  
}

#plot it
df <- data.frame(i=samp_list %>% log10(), y=res)

ggplot(df, aes(x=i, y=y)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(col="Red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.8)
```

Is there an algebraic expression that given n and p yields d?

References and derivation appreciated.  Also, if it is known by a different name, please let me know the proper terminology.

Comment: The meanings of your terms "samples" and "values" are ambiguous.  Would a "sample" be a *single object* and a "value" be an *outcome?*  Is it possible for distinct objects in the population to have the same "value"?

Comment: @whuber - is this less bad?

Comment: Would it be correct to view this as closely related to the distribution in the [Coupon Collector's problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector+distribution)?

Comment: @whuber - yes!  Didn't know about [coupon collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  Partial fulfillment means there are a multiplicity of ways to not get everything.  If there are 100 coupons, while there is one way to get 100% of them, there are 100 ways to get 99% of coupons.  There are (I think) 4950 ways to get 98%.  If you are looking for 80% then there are 5e20 ways to get it.

Comment: I believe Ben answers your question -- or at least sketches a way to answer it, with references -- at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257924.