# Card Collecting Odds

Tags: probability, odds

My friends and I are thinking about participating in an event to collect these cards. There are 8 total cards in the set, and we can buy a pack of 10 random cards at a discount. So we were wondering, what is the % chance that we get all 8 of the unique cards in our 10 card pack (assuming each card has an equal chance)? I can't figure out how to calculate it.

Comment: You count the number of equally probable ways of getting a full set, and divide it by the total number of equally probable ways your $10$ cards might be distributed

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: This is part of the [coupon collector problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=coupon%20collector).  Although the original problem asks for the expectation of how many cards you need until you see all eight of them, [some of our threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88156/919) include formulas for the full distribution, so all you have to do is plug the numbers 8 and 10 into the formulas.